# ASCII code for subscript and superscript not wroking in nexus

Tags: javascript

I have tried to print subscripts using both Unicode and ASCII code from 1 to 9. They work well everywhere except from nexus 7. In nexus 7 they work only up to 3 beyond that it prints nothing.
The part of code i tried

```
    myobj.find('.sx4').unbind('click').on("click", function () {
                    myobj.find('.bg_img').hide();
                    myobj.find('.operator').show();
                    myobj.find('.inputval').insertAtCaret('₄');
                });
```

Can anyone suggest something else or point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Then it probably doesn't have a font installed with those characters. Either use more compatible `<sub>` HTML tags to achieve the same effect, or embed a web font which contains these characters.

Comment: Can you suggest some font which contains these characters.